# Generate XSD Elements dynamically depending upon the value of an existing xsd element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD:

```
   <xs:element name="TRANRESP">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="RECEIPT" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element ref="RECEIPTLINES" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

.....

```
 <xs:element name="RECEIPT"/>
  <xs:element name="RECEIPTLINES"/>
```

I need to add RECEIPT{1} to RECEIPT{N} dynamically depending upon the value of RECEIPTLINES in integer. {N} represents an integer number. I need to have one to many relationship between RECEIPTLINES and RECEIPT{N}.

Like: If the value of RECEIPTLINES is 5. I need to generate RECEIPT1, RECEIPT2 ... RECEIPT5.

Can I do this? 
If yes, how? I can change the XSD. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can do it using XSD 1.1, but not using XSD 1.0 AFAIK. Does your processor supports XSD 1.1?

Comment: Note also that XSD is concerned with *validation*, not generation.

Comment: @sergioFC : My processor supports XSD 1.1 ... I need to try for that

Comment: The xs:choice of the question is not closed. In addition, I don't understand why you have choosen an xs:choice instead of a xs:sequence, could you please explain it? It would be great if you provide XML examples explaining why it should or not be valid.

Comment: sequence is not an issue for me. I need elements in any order and any number.  My question is regarding the dynamic generation of xsd elements ...

Comment: I have closed the tag. thanks  !!

Comment: Who is supposed to generate the elements?

Comment: Java Code needs to be written for generating the elements or if there can be anything in xsd ....